# Unable to locate elements in Sharepoint modal window with Selenium

Tags: selenium, sharepoint

Using Selenium, I'm uploading a file to SharePoint, using upload.aspx in a modal window (So, this is SharePoint out-of-the-box.  For whatever reason, I am unable to locate the iframe that SharePoint is using.  Can anyone suggest to me a useful technique for this, in SharePoint?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and came up with the following code. This works even if frame name or ID changes dynamically.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//iframe[@src='yourFrameSourceFromHTML']")));
```